# Правильно ли будет наследовать DTO-класс от класса-сущности?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, наследование, проектирование, интерфейс

### Вариант #1 (текущий)

Есть вот такая диаграмма классов в виде кода:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    public int Experience { get; set; } //стаж работы
}

public class StudentDto
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    public string ClassName { get; set; }
}
```

---

### Вариант #2

Я не стал в первом варианте наследовать класс `StudentDto` от `Person` по причине того, что на мой взгляд `Student` и `Teacher` это одно семейство, а `StudentDto` и т.п. другое и было бы не правильно в первую очередь с **концептуальной** точки зрения наследовать `StudentDto` от `Person`.

И насколько подсказывает мне мое понимание разницы использования абстрактного класса от интерфейса, так это то, что это как раз один из тех моментов, где лучше использовать интерфейс **когда разные семейства имеют какой-то одинаковый функционал**.

И теперь я хочу сделать следующйй рефакторинг:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Surname { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string SecondName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : IPerson
{        
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : IPerson
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    public int Experience { get; set; }
}

public class StudentDto : IPerson
{        
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    public string ClassName { get; set; }
}
```

---

### Вопрос

Насколько прав я был в своих суждениях и есть ли преимущество второго варианта перед первым?

Comment: Не вижу наследования. Реализация интерфейса - не наследование.

Comment: @vitidev, в варианте #1 ведь наследование.

Comment: public class StudentDto....и все и ваши же слова "Я не стал в первом варианте наследовать класс StudentDto от Person". Где наследование?  Впрочем, это неважно. DTO  - логический акцент на том, что объект нужен для переноса данных. То есть он как бы заявляет, что  он не защищает те данные, что переносит (нет инкапсуляции) и не вызывает внутри себя разные там сервисы при изменении данных.

Comment: @vitidev, _не защищает те данные, что переносит_ тут я не совсем согласен. К примеру, мы в этом объекте часто устанавливаем атрибуты для его свойств при помощи которых валидируем сам объект.

Comment: Dto из своего названия служит для переноса данных. По существу это как коробка, которую нужно куда-то передать. При этом по пути может быть сериализация. Дело коробки - нести данные, а не заниматься вопросами их правильности. Практически нет причин для наследования, ну разве что если лень руками писать свойства. А интерфейс нужен разве что для "подсунуть dto вместо основноый сущности", но это плохой дизайн.

Comment: Вообще все это условности. DTO, Entity, ValueObject все это названия определяющие предназначение  класса. Тот же anemic model выглядит как dto, а используется по другому. Иметь ли методы в DTO - ну это фломастеры. Главное понять что основное предназначение dto - перенос между границами слоев/модулей/систем/... то есть туда, где не знают про IPerson/IPerson, к тому же dto определен в общей сборке (+не совпадает по контракту с сущносятми). Или же это внутри одной системы, но модуль хотят изолировать от знания других частей системы. И наследование ломает тут всё.